# how can I disable same site cookies flags after latest update of chrome(93)?

Tags: google-chrome, samesite

after recent update of chrome, I can't login in on my local project because SameSite cookies disabling flags are removed, I searched a lot and found some tips for appending bellow command to the end of target but still it doesn't work.
how to use chrome for development after this update?

```
--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies
```

Answer (score 1):

We tried some different ways but none of them worked. finally we had switch to https

Answer (score -1):

There seems google disabled this feature.

```
Mar 18, 2021: The flags #same-site-by-default-cookies and #cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure have been removed from chrome://flags as of Chrome 91, as the behavior is now enabled by default. In Chrome 94, the command-line flag --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure will be removed.
```

Go to `chrome://flags/` then search `cookies` in the search box, there should be 4 options.
Check **Enable removing SameSite=None cookies** and **Consider SameParty cookies to be first-party** sections.
It maybe helps.

Comment: thank you for the response, but it didn't work